# tablesorter pager print

Tags: tablesorter

I use jquery tablesorter with pager.

I search a way that the printed version of the page show all items (not just the list visible).

example: you got a list of 25 elements. with a pager set to 10 element. On page 1 you will see the first 10 elements. on this page, you call Print. The result is the list of 25 elements.

Answer (score 2):

If you happen to be using my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/), you have two choices:

1. Set the pager plugin option `removeRows` to `false`, then include this in your css stylesheet:

   ```
   @media print {
     table.tablesorter tbody tr {
       display: table-row !important;
     }
   }
   ```

   This method will also work if the filter widget is active.
2. Disable the pager plugin before printing as follows:

   ```
   // use $('table.tablesorter').trigger('enable.pager'); to re-enable the pager
   $('table.tablesorter').trigger('disable.pager');
   ```

This is reposted from [here](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/42).